# Custom std::get with a class inheritant of std::tuple

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have created a class than inherit from `std::tuple` as:

```cpp
template<class, class>
struct tuple_prepend;

template<class T, class ...Ts>
struct tuple_prepend<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
};

template<class ...Ts>
struct tuple_optional_impl;

template<class T, class ...Ts>
struct tuple_optional_impl<T, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename tuple_prepend<std::optional<T>, typename tuple_optional_impl<Ts...>::type>::type;
};

template<class T>
struct tuple_optional_impl<T>
{
    using type = std::tuple<std::optional<T>>;
};

template<class ...Ts>
struct tuple_optional;

template<class ...Ts>
struct tuple_optional<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = typename tuple_optional_impl<Ts...>::type;
};

template<class ...Ts>
class Tuple : public tuple_optional<std::tuple<Ts...>>::type
{
};
```

`tuple_optional`: convert an `std::tuple<T>` into `std::tuple<std::optional<T>>` and have the same behavior with `Ts...`.

I would like to make a custom `std::get<T>` to handle `Tuple`, I have this implementation:

```cpp
namespace std
{
    template<class T, class ...Ts>
    std::optional<T> get(Tuple<Ts...> &_tuple) noexcept
    {
        return std::get<std::optional<T>>(static_cast<tuple_optional<std::tuple<Ts...>>::type>(_tuple));
    }
}
```

But the `static_cast` generate this error:

> error C2100: illegal indirection

> message : see the reference at the instanciation of model:  'std::optionalecs::comp::HitBox std::getecs::comp::HitBox,ecs::comp::Stat,ecs::comp::Position,ecs::comp::HitBox,ecs::comp::Rotation,ecs::comp::Id(Tupleecs::comp::Stat,ecs::comp::Position,ecs::comp::HitBox,ecs::comp::Rotation,ecs::comp::Id &) noexcept' at compilation

I don't wan't to use an `alias` or erase the inheritance.

Comment: why do you want to inherit? Why not use `tuple_optional<...>::type` ?

Comment: The `Error` pane in Visual Studio shows error *summaries*. The full error appears in the `Output` pane.

Comment: Also, your overloaded `get` is unnecessary.  The normal `std::get` works 100% on your `Tuple` class already.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the complete compiler error message

Comment: I wan't to inherit, because it's more practical and readable.

Comment: @DipStax: If you want practical and readable, use `template<class ...Ts>
using Tuple = tuple_optional<std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;` instead.

Comment: I dont quite understand. How is defining a new type to inherit from some type `X` simpler than just using `X` directly? edit: well ok, if you were not aware of the option to use a alias template, then I do understand ;)

Comment: Omitting the alias and the non-inheritance, how can I solve this error?

Comment: @MooingDuck unless I'm missing something, why not `template<class ...Ts> using Tuple = std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>;`?

Comment: @Caleth it isn't cross compatible.

Comment: what do you mean with "cross compatible" ? cross what? why do you not want to use an alias?

Comment: @DipStax ??? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c17f59ed0ffdefb7

Comment: your approach is fundamentally flawed (eg adding to `std` is a no go). If you want us to suggest working alternatives and you don't want the obvious ones then you need to be very clear about the reasons and the requirements, otherwise the question will stay unclear

Comment: When you do it with MVSC, you got this error: `error C2977: 'std::optional' : number of argument to high`

Comment: @DipStax are you trying `std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>;` or `std::tuple<std::optional<Ts...>>;`? The former is what I wrote, the latter is ill-formed for most `Ts...`

Comment: perhaps you should open a new question to ask about the code with that error, rather than some workaround that appears strange to anybody not aware of the issue you are trying to work around ([What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: My bad, I was using `std::tuple<std::optional<Ts...>>`, so you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any of that.

```
template<class ...Ts> using Tuple = std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>;
```